# Sets operator equal to

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have actually two questions.

Determine if the following is true:

a) $(A - B) - C = A - (B - C)$

b) If $A \cup B = A \cap B$, then $A = B$

$A$ and $B$ are sets.

In part(a), $$A-B = A \cap B^c$$

$A - (B - C)$

$=A - (B\cap C^c)$

$=A\cap (B^c\cup C)$

$=(A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap C)$

$=(A-B)\cup (A\cap C)$

$\neq (A - B) - C$

So can I prove it in this way and is it correct?

And in part(b), I think it is correct?

$A\cap B = ${1, 2}

$A\cup B = ${1, 2}

So $A =$ {1, 2} and $B =$ {1, 2}

Comment: You are correct. (b) is true.

Comment: How about part b??

Comment: Make a counter-example in (a) and to prove (b) just look at the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that (b) is true. However, in general to prove a property is false, you must exhibit a counter-example, since you have not technically proven that (a) is false. Try to come up with three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, where $(A-B)-C\not= A-(B-C)$.

***Hint:*** $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, and $C=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: So I have to try something like $A ={1,2}$ etc...?

Comment: okay, I know what you mean, so part a is incorrect and part b is correct?

Comment: That's right...though, you should prove (b) from the definitions.

Comment: Can I do it as the above edition??